# Pandas Difference from two DateTime64[ns] columns - Shows "-1 days" when goes through midnight

Tags: pandas, datetime

Goal is to compute delta between two times, each in separate DF columns and in 24-Hour clock format, and add to a new column "triptime"

Here is my input code, which has no dates,  just 24hour clock strings.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DepartureTime': ['2330', '1700', '0900'], 'ArrivalTime': ['0030','1900','1100']})
```

Here is my attempt

```
df['DepartureTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DepartureTime, format='%H%M')
df['ArrivalTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ArrivalTime, format='%H%M')
df['triptime'] = df.ArrivalTime - df.DepartureTime
```

Which outputs a problem as can be seen in the first row below. Unfortunately my pipeline data assumes no change in dates. Any guidance on how I can have the triptime column showing the actual trip time, without prefix of days?

[image]

Comment: a general note, departure and arrival times without date (and preferably UTC offset) seem pretty painful to work with to me. so if you have the chance to get a date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can add `astype()` to return only the difference in hours.

```
df['triptime'] = (df.ArrivalTime - df.DepartureTime).astype('timedelta64[h]')
#output
    DepartureTime       ArrivalTime         triptime
0   1900-01-01 23:30:00 1900-01-01 00:30:00 -23.0
1   1900-01-01 17:00:00 1900-01-01 19:00:00 2.0
2   1900-01-01 09:00:00 1900-01-01 11:00:00 2.0
```

---

One way to get the interval when the day turns is to select all values ​​less than zero and add 24. Apparently it solves the problem but it is not something I like. It seems highly susceptible to errors.

```
df.loc[df['triptime'] < 0, 'triptime'] = df['triptime'] + 24
#output
    DepartureTime       ArrivalTime         triptime
0   1900-01-01 23:30:00 1900-01-01 00:30:00 1.0
1   1900-01-01 17:00:00 1900-01-01 19:00:00 2.0
2   1900-01-01 09:00:00 1900-01-01 11:00:00 2.0
```

The most correct and fail-safe way would be to have, in addition to the time of departure and arrival, the entire dates

---

If after calculations you want to remove the dates and keep only the hours, use `.dt.time`

```
df['DepartureTime'] = df['DepartureTime'].dt.time
df['ArrivalTime'] = df['ArrivalTime'].dt.time
#output
    DepartureTime   ArrivalTime triptime
0   23:30:00        00:30:00    1.0
1   17:00:00        19:00:00    2.0
2   09:00:00        11:00:00    2.0
```

Comment: thanks. however the first row gives a trip time of -23 hours - I think I need a way to drop the date prefix, that way there is no confusion

Comment: @Prolle can you post in the question how is the expected output?